# How to express one predicate by means of another one?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, predicate, negation

I have a predicate "HAVE", now I need a predicare "don'tHave". How to create such predicate using existing predicate "HAVE"?

Comment: honestly, I don't like those properties like "have" etc.  - what is the semantics of "have" then? Is it really meaningful in your domain? Can you give examples of data that use "have" and "don't have" in your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OWL, whose assertions are under open-world assumption, it is sufficient to declare such properties as disjoint, in such a way that, if you state `:x :DontHave :y .`, then you'll know that `:x :Have :y` is false.

**Functional-Style Syntax**

```
DisjointObjectProperties( :Have :DontHave )
```

**RDF/XML Syntax**

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="Have">
  <owl:propertyDisjointWith rdf:resource="DontHave"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

**Turtle Syntax**

```
:Have  owl:propertyDisjointWith  :DontHave .
```

**Manchester Syntax**

```
DisjointProperties: Have, DontHave
```

**OWL/XML Syntax**

```
<DisjointObjectProperties>
  <ObjectProperty IRI="Have"/>
  <ObjectProperty IRI="DontHave"/>
</DisjointObjectProperties>
```

Comment: Notice that this is closely related to the equivalence between the logical expressions `A → ¬B` (one implies the other negated), `A ∧ B → ⊥` (proper disjointness) or  `⊤ → ¬A ∨ ¬B` (one of the two must be false).